# Creating the volume of an object as fog

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, fog

I'm working with fog shaders in Unity, and I've created following shader:
[image]

However, this shader is just taking a texture and slides it over the surface of the object. It work's fine for 2D fog, but I want to also create a shader which fills the volume of an object. I'm aware of the in-built fog effect in Unity, but would like something I can concentrate to the size of an object.

Is this something achievable through shaders, or do I have to go a different route? I tried messing with the ShaderLab: Legacy Fog, but it seems to be outdated and unable to work effectively.

Comment: I think that shaders will not help you to achieve this effect, because they are meant to work with surfaces and you want to fill some volume with fog. But it's just my opinion and maybe I'm wrong. UPD: maybe particles will do the trick.

Comment: Yea I figured. I did however find this, which works somewhat: https://forum.unity.com/threads/spherical-fog-shader-shared-project.269771/

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this, most of them fall in the category of the **fog volumes**. If you're new to shader programming the task might be a bit daunting, but there are samples and assets around you can use.

The issue is that shaders are only aware of global constants and local information of the point being processed (so a given pixel has no access to a description of its surroundings). To achieve what you want the pixel needs some information about the shape it belongs to, or its environment.

The simplest approach to this for arbitrary meshes is to sample the depth of the scene at that point (pre-rendered and stored in a texture). [There are a bunch of macro to help you with that](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DepthTextures.html). Once you know the depth behind the point and the depth of the point itself you can do a bunch of operation to figure out the intensity of the fog for that point.

You can look at the soft particle shader in the [built-in shaders](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) , which is doing that exact process to fade objects as they get closer to other opaque geometries.